# PHP sdk become() issue throws PHP warnings on invalid login

Tags: php, parse-platform

I am not sure why this is happening, and I can't seem to find a similar entry, so here goes:

I have a website that links to Parse cloud via JS and PHP. The user logs in on one page and is then redirected to a sub-domain upon successful validation via JavaScript. The sessionToken is passed via a GET request. The validation works in JavaScript, and if valid token is passed to PHP everything is fine. The problem is in PHP when an invalid token is send in the request I get several warnings. I am using a try/catch block, but for some reason I get the following:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.parse.com/1/users/me): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseClient.php on line 240

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseObject.php on line 494

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseObject.php on line 534
```

PHP code:

```
if( !$user = ParseUser::getCurrentUser() ) {
   //get session token from url
   $token = isset( $_GET['sessionToken'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_GET['sessionToken'] ) : wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com?error=no_session', 301 );
  //assign user via sessionToken
  try {
     $user = ParseUser::become( $token );
  } catch(ParseException $ex ) {
      //invaild sessionToken - redirect to main site 
      wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com?error=invalid_session_token&error_code=' . $error->getCode() . '&message=' . $error->getMessage(), 301 );    
  }
 };
}
```

I am sure that the login script is working in JS and the become() call works if the session is valid. There must be a way to process an invalid login without throwing warnings. I would think the error would be caught in the catch block, but it is not. The subdomain is SSL if that makes a difference.

Hope this is enough info, any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Most of PHP will not natively throw exceptions, so your `try/catch` won't be effective in preventing `foreach` errors.  So I understand, the ternary you use with `$token = isset(...)` is intended to retrieve `sessionToken` if it is set, and if not, redirect via a WP redirection function? That is kind of an abuse of the ternary, since `wp_redirect()` isn't returning a value to store into `$token`. A plain `if/else` would make more sense here.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that due to a logic problem with your ternary operation assigning `$token`, your code is not redirecting away on an invalid value as intended.

The `x = a ? b : c` is meant to *return* or *assign* values, but not to execute procedural logic. Your "else" case in the `$token` ternary calls `wp_redirect()` in a way that is not intended to return a value to `$token`. That turns out to cause some problems.

Looking [at the source code for `wp_redirect()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1147), the function does not call `exit()/die()` on completion.  When PHP issues a redirect via a `Location` call with `header()`, code following the redirection *will still be executed* unless the script is explicitly terminated with `exit()/die()`.

Indeed, if you look at [examples of how Wordpress itself calls `wp_redirect()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1002), they are always followed by `exit()`.

So even though you try to redirect away, your subsequent code block executes with an invalid `$token` variable. This is compounded by the fact that most of PHP's core does not natively implement exceptions. The `try/catch` you wrapped around it does has no exceptions to catch from the `foreach` error and isn't helpful there.

So the best way to handle this is with a regular old `if/else` block instead of the ternary operator. After successful assignment to `$token`, do the parse action in the same `if` block.  If the token wasn't set, redirect in the outer `else`. *Always* make an `exit()` call after the redirection.

```
if( !$user = ParseUser::getCurrentUser() ) {
  //assign user via sessionToken
  // Sanitize the token if it was passed in the URL
  if (isset($_GET['sessionToken'])) {
    $token = sanitize_text_field($_GET['sessionToken']);
    // Then call the parser since the token is known to be set
    try {
      $user = ParseUser::become($token);
    }
    catch(ParseException $ex ) {
      //invaild sessionToken - redirect to main site 
      // Not certain what $error is here  -- was that intended to be $ex->getCode()/$ex->getMessage()
      // since the ParseException is thrown as $ex??
      wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com?error=invalid_session_token&error_code=' . $error->getCode() . '&message=' . $error->getMessage(), 301 );
      // Explicitly exit() after redirection (always do this!)
      exit();
    }
  }
  else {
    // Redirect if the token wasn't passed and again, explicitly exit()!
    wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com?error=no_session', 301 );
    exit();
  }
```

#### Addendum:

Separate from the logic issues you were facing, significant research into the source code points out that the error related to `file_get_contents()` is related to using an old version of the API software library.  [The current version of the software does not call `file_get_contents()`](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk/blob/master/src/Parse/ParseClient.php#L246), and instead uses cURL and throws exceptions on 404 errors.

You needed to update the library via composer with:

```
composer update
```

Comment: I see that now. Thanks I will make the corrections and see if that works....rookie mistake on my part.

Comment: @Jusmark123 I just looked at this and noticed I had left in the original ternary due to a copy/paste error XD sorry about that, corrected.

Comment: That didn't work still the same issue...I even tried using PHP only.      Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.parse.com/1/login?username=username&password=password): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /inc/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseClient.php on line 240

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /inc/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseObject.php on line 494

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /inc/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseObject.php on line 534.    There has to be a reason for this.

Comment: @Jusmark123 Are you using the most recent version of the Parse sdk? Did you `composer update` it? The current code on github does not call `file_get_contents()` at all, and instead uses curl. It does appear to throw an exception when it can't return data or issues a bad request https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk/blob/master/src/Parse/ParseClient.php#L246

Comment: @Jusmark123 The 2 errors aren't the same - your original was a 404 on `/1/me` and this is an error with `/1/login`.  Both of those suggest that the API version or URIs have changed or are otherwise incorrect. If the API is returning 404, that probably isn't an issue with your PHP code at all and should be a support request for them.  But first, you should verify that you have the most up to date version of this PHP library because it doens't look like it calls `file_get_contents()` anywhere in the `ParseClient` class as your error is saying.

Comment: Finally, please verify that it is in fact the `become()` call which is failing and not earlier in `getCurrentUser()`, where I have't fully traced the sdk

Comment: @Jusmark123 I see you have comment below posted as an answer (which was deleted by moderators). To complete this question, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark. I'll add the part about composer updating above.